# Phrase matching for keys in redis

Tags: redis, pattern-matching, glob

I have the following keys in redis :

```
"542 136 mountain road"
"542 136 mountainview road"
"542136 mountain road"
"542 136 mountain"
"136 mountain road"
"136 mountain"
```

I would like to get the keys which contains the phrase `136 mountain`.
With the glob-style pattern, I am currently making 4 queries so as to satisfy all the possible cases .

```
scan 0 MATCH '*[\ ]136 mountain[\ ]*'

scan 0 MATCH '*[\ ]136 mountain'

scan 0 MATCH '136 mountain[\ ]*'

scan 0 MATCH '136 mountain'
```

These four queries in total would return 4 results :

```
"542 136 mountain road"
"542 136 mountain"
"136 mountain road"
"136 mountain"
```

Please do share your inputs if there is any better way of changing the pattern string so that all the 4 results can be obtained in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be achieved with a glob-style pattern.

I would also note that even if there was a pattern that matched the phrases presented, due to the nature of how SCAN works you would need to iterate through the entire dataset (making separate calls) to get the results you are looking for.  Then you would need to consider the fact your data may be changing during the iteration period.

**From the docs**

> It is important to note that the MATCH filter is applied after
>   elements are retrieved from the collection, just before returning data
>   to the client. This means that if the pattern matches very little
>   elements inside the collection, SCAN will likely return no elements in
>   most iterations.

Reference: https://redis.io/commands/scan#the-match-option

--

**Option 1**

Use **SCAN** to iterate through the entire dataset and further filter the data at the application level.

**Option 2**

Depending on what type of guarantees you're looking for and how much data you have, you could use **KEYS**. This is generally not a recommended approach, but it's an option to consider.

Example:
`KEYS '*136 mountain*'`

Much like the **SCAN** approach, you will have a larger response than what you are looking for and will need to use your language of choice to further filter the result.

**Option 3**

Index your data by doing some preprocessing at the application level. If the key matches your desired pattern add it to a **SET** / **Sorted Set**.

**Option 4**

Write a Lua script.